# How i can await the result of the AsyncStorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i need to run the AsyncStorage first before run the other functions , but AsyncStorage take a time to run and it give the resutlt in the end of the code

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  
  AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN).then((r) => {
    console.log("AsyncStorage Function")
  })

  this.state = { token: null } 
  console.log("The last Function")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't be performing any async tasks inside a constructor assuming this is a react class component.

So if you wish to perform any async tasks you could make use of [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) from the component lifecycle method.

But in general if you want to wait for the async operation then this can be achieved in different ways

### Using Promises

```js
const promiseFun = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

promiseFun().then((res) => {
  //here res will be what is returned from the promise function
  console.log(res);

  //All the required things that needed to be perfomed after the async operation should be placed here.
});


//Whatever the actions/statements written here will be executed before the async operation is finished
console.log("Before Promise Returned");
```

### Using async/await

```js
const promiseFun = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const execFun = async() => {
  let res = await promiseFun();
  //All the statments from here will be executed only after the promise/async function returned. 
  console.log(res);
  
}

execFun();
//All the statements here will be executed without waiting for the promise/async function gets executed 
console.log("Before Promise Returned");
```